# Java ArrayList java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist, static, nullpointerexception

I'm sorry I am very new to programming and have encountered what I hope is a simple problem to solve.
I'll put my code in here and explain what I am trying to do below.

```
public class main {

static ArrayList<Interpreter> ints1;
static ArrayList<Customer> custs1;
static MainFunctions mainF;

static { //Static blocks execute first - and are great for initializing data!
    ArrayListPopulator ALP1 = new ArrayListPopulator();
    ints1 = ALP1.populateALints1(); // error occurs on this method call.
    custs1 = ALP1.populateALcusts1();
    mainF = new MainFunctions(ints1, custs1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    mainF.findNearestInterp("Frank");
}
```

}

ArrayList Populator:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayListPopulator {

private ArrayList<Interpreter> ints1ToGo;
private ArrayList<Customer> custs1ToGo;

public ArrayList<Interpreter> populateALints1() {
    //Format is "String pName, int pAge, String PGender,
            // int pSignLevel, boolean pDeafBlindExp, double pLatitude, double pLongitude, String pTown"

            //Gender must be "Male"||"Female"

            //In future this could be done by scanning a local config text file. Wish that I knew that stuff :l

    Interpreter Elliott = new Interpreter("Elliott", 23, "Male", 6, true, 52.098049, 0.277860, "Linton");
    ints1ToGo.add(Elliott); //error occurs here.

    Interpreter Sarah = new Interpreter("Sarah", 20, "Female", 3, true, 52.209950, 0.137774, "Cambridge");
    ints1ToGo.add(Sarah);

    Interpreter Argibarge = new Interpreter("Argibarge", 42, "Male", 3, false, 52.599199, -0.264226, "Peterborough");
    ints1ToGo.add(Argibarge);

    Interpreter Bruce = new Interpreter("Bruce", 30, "Male", 2, false, 50.717527, -3.540192, "Exeter");
    ints1ToGo.add(Bruce);

    Interpreter Medusa = new Interpreter("Medusa", 1009, "Female", 4, false, 55.867795, -4.267566, "Glasgow");
    ints1ToGo.add(Medusa);

    return ints1ToGo;
}

public ArrayList<Customer> populateALcusts1() {
    //Format is "String pName, int pAge, String PGender,
    //boolean pDeafBlind, double pLatitude, double pLongitude, String pTown"

    //Gender must be "Male"||"Female"

    //In future this could be done by scanning a local config text file. Wish that I knew that stuff :l

    Customer Frank = new Customer("Frank", 30, "Male", false, 56.113482, -3.934635, "Stirling");
    custs1ToGo.add(Frank);

    Customer Eleanor = new Customer("Eleanor", 23, "Female", true, 52.622439, 1.281124, "Norwich");
    custs1ToGo.add(Eleanor);

    Customer Pacha = new Customer("Pacha", 43, "Male", false, 52.397273, -0.727392, "Kettering");
    custs1ToGo.add(Pacha);

    Customer Roy = new Customer("Roy", 69, "Male", false, 51.746940, -1.257345, "Oxford");
    custs1ToGo.add(Roy);

    Customer Jenette = new Customer("Jenette", 16, "Male", false, 51.871877, 0.357845, "Great Dunmow");
    custs1ToGo.add(Jenette);
    return custs1ToGo;
}
```

}

Error Message at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ArrayListPopulator.populateALints1(ArrayListPopulator.java:16)
at main.<clinit>(main.java:23)
```

The thing I am most new to in this code is the static {} block to initialize my main ArrayLists of data from the data stored in the ArrayListPopulator class. It would appear that I am not initializing the ArrayList properly, or adding the elements properly, or I'm not assigning the reference variable properly.

*Thank you so much for any help!*

Comment: what does line 16 refer to?

Comment: Are you initializing your ArrayList collections anywhere?

Comment: "Static blocks execute first - and are great for initializing data" and are great for causing difficulties with unit testing, mocking, controlling initialisation order between modules etc. Use with care. I would much prefer initialisation in a constructor

Comment: line 16 refers to a function taking a customers name and comparing it to the database of interpreters and their distance from the customer - however it is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so helpful in answering my first question here :) I hope one day to be able to share some knowledge in return!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ints1ToGo` list is not initialized.

*Either* do it in the constructor:

```
public ArrayListPopulator() {
    ints1ToGo = new ArrayList<Interpreter>();
}
```

*or* before you try to add elements.

```
ints1ToGo = new ArrayList<Interpreter>();
Interpreter Elliott = new Interpreter("Elliott", 23, "Male", 6, true, 52.098049, 0.277860, "Linton");
ints1ToGo.add(Elliott); //error won't occur here anymore.
```

**Note that** you will have to do the same for the `custs1ToGo` list, because (as I can see) you're not initializing it anywhere and it's used in the `populateALcusts1` method.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `ints1ToGo`:

```
ints1ToGo = new ArrayList<Interpreter>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ints1ToGo` is never initialized. Change `private ArrayList<Interpreter> ints1ToGo;` to `private ArrayList<Interpreter> ints1ToGo = new ArrayList<Interpreter>();`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize both array instances

```
private ArrayList<Interpreter> ints1ToGo = new ArrayList<Interperter>();
private ArrayList<Customer> custs1ToGo = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```